# Login with Facebook/Twitter - Authentication

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I am thinking of adding a login with twitter OR facebook on my website.

Although, I am in a doubt on how to do this. I have a normal registration system on my website, and I authenticate the users by sessions.

If I wish to intregrate the "login with facebook" and "login with twitter", how would the best way to store the users in my database?

I know that when users are logging in with facebook/twitte, a token is stored.

I have a users table with many columns like:

username, email, balance, clicks etc. etc.

What would be the best way? Is it better to use register with facebook or register with twitter (does that even exist?)

I am using PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it exists. You can simply use facbook api for that purpose. you can go through http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=730
and it gives you data in return which you can save in your db for further process. Like facebook user id , username and etc but not the password (remember) and same way for twitter

Comment: I see. So, first time a user logins with ex. Facebook on my site, I store the data into the database. All other times, it will JUST take that data stored the first time and use?

As I do not want to store each time a user logins with facebook/twitter.

Comment: I just don't get how I can do, so it only stores the users information the first time they login with facebook/twitter.

Comment: when first time user logins you will save the data to the db. When ever user will login with facebook again you will have to update your data accordingly. Its need for the case if (lets say if a user logins in ur website from fb with username XXX and then he/she change it to YYY but if you will not update it then it will be XXX on your website where you will show it from your db) hope you got my point.

Comment: I get your point. So, I have to, whenever a user logins, compare the data he is logging in with, and the data that I have in my DB?

Comment: yes and update it accordingly. Its required only if you want to show data like username in your website. Otherwise authentications and logins are managed by facebook api. its the beauty of that api. it handles all by themselves.